# Is this inefficient Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have some Javascript similar to this:

`var  a = localStorage.getItem(_key) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(_key)) : null;`

Is this efficient or will it result in a redundant call in the case that `_key` does indeed exist? Would this alternative offer a significant performance improvement?

```
var k = localStorage.getItem(_key);
var a = k ? JSON.parse(k) : null;
```

Note that I am working with large arrays of objects stored in HTML5 `localStorage`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but can't you measure your JavaScript performance questions with the, appropriately named, [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/)?

Comment: I'm sure the spec has something to say about this. Like max 20 reads and max 100 writes (for 1 key) per second. Or not. Do the google dance!

Comment: JSON.parse(k) will return null anyway if there's no item available, so therefore your check is unnecessary.

Comment: @zvona that code will throw an illegal access exception on old Android Browsers (that's how I used to do it before I found out)

Comment: @OmarMeky OK, that explains a lot.

Comment: @Rudie: No, the spec is about behaviour not performance.

Comment: To answer your direct question.  If the key exists, your first code example will result in two calls to `localStorage` which is less efficient than getting the value once and then testing it.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's not at all necessarily true. `localStorage`'s caching might be more efficient than a local `var`.

Comment: @Rudie - are you saying that a function call to a native implemented method is more efficient than simply accessing a local variable in javascript?  Good luck with that idea.  Feel free to prove me wrong with a jsperf if you want.

Comment: @Rudie - I invite you to prove me wrong.  Function calls in JS are slow.  Local variable accesses are not near as slow.

Comment: For readability and maintainability alone, the second version would seem to make more sense. I'm occasionally working on code that has all conditions written as the first version, and programmers copy'n'pasting generates mismatches between the first and second call. Not fun to track down.

Comment: @Rudie - see here: http://jsperf.com/local-storage-vs-local-variable.  Local variable access 250x faster than localStorage call in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

> will it result in a redundant call in the case that _key does indeed exist?

Yes, obviously.

> Would this alternative offer a significant performance improvement?

It will be faster, yes, but whether it's "significant" you will have to test yourself. Btw, if you care about that second variable you could as well do

```
var a = localStorage.getItem(_key);
if (a) a = JSON.parse(a);
```

Comment: Or even `a && (a = JSON.parse(a))`. Is that faster than an explicit `if`? =)

Comment: @Rudie: No, I'd expect both to compile to the same bytecode. Possibly the operator a bit slower because it needs to care about return values. Also, the if-statement is definitely more readable.

Comment: It does not appear to be significant for my purposes but of course it is faster: http://jsperf.com/check-local-storage-exists